# How to hide everything within "ul" element if there are no "li" elements contained using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have multiple unordered lists that contain a heading and list items, however, some unordered lists do not have list items and I want to hide the heading title for this specific list (i.e. "Candy").

I have tried using `.hide()` and multiple different variations of `.css("display","none")`.

I expect the "Snacks" and "Drinks" list to remain while the "Candy" and "Desserts" unordered list to be hidden, therefore not showing the titles if empty.

```js
if (!$("ul.qrg-products").has("li").length) {
  $(".qrg-products").css("display", "none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <h2 class="title">Snack</h2>
  <li>Chips</li>
  <li>Fruit</li>
  <li>Cookies</li>
</ul>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <h2 class="title">Candy</h2>
</ul>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <h2 class="title">Drinks</h2>
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Water</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <h2 class="title">Desserts</h2>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why would you have invalid HTML? Fix your HTML first

Comment: An `ul` can only have `li` as children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your HTML is invalid, so I moved the `h2` into a `li`.

Then there's no reason to use a script for this, CSS and its `:only-child` will be perfect.

Stack snippet

```css
.qrg-products > li:first-child {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.qrg-products > li:only-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <li><h2 class="title">Snack</h2></li>
  <li>Chips</li>
  <li>Fruit</li>
  <li>Cookies</li>
</ul>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <li><h2 class="title">Candy</h2></li>
</ul>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <li><h2 class="title">Drinks</h2></li>
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Water</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <li><h2 class="title">Desserts</h2></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have valid HTML

If you move the Headers you need to hide them using .prev - I choose toggle here.

You can also move the header into an li and toggle on length === 1

```js
$("ul.qrg-products").each(function() {
  var len = $(this).find("li").length > 0
  $(this).toggle(len>0); // not super necessary since empty
  $(this).prev().toggle(len>0); // hide the Header
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="title">Snack</h2>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <li>Chips</li>
  <li>Fruit</li>
  <li>Cookies</li>
</ul>
<h2 class="title">Candy</h2>
<ul class="qrg-products">
</ul>
<h2 class="title">Drinks</h2>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Water</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>
<h2 class="title">Desserts</h2>
<ul class="qrg-products">
</ul>
```

If you cannot change the HTML:

```js
$("ul.qrg-products").each(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).find("li").length>0)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <h2 class="title">Snack</h2>
  <li>Chips</li>
  <li>Fruit</li>
  <li>Cookies</li>
</ul>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <h2 class="title">Candy</h2>
</ul>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <h2 class="title">Drinks</h2>
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Water</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <h2 class="title">Desserts</h2>
</ul>
```

Comment: I advise to fix the HTML twice on this page

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid, since `<ul>` elements can only contain `<li>` elements.

After moving the `<h2>` elements out, you can check for empty `<ul>` elements, and for each of them find the previous sibling, and hide it:

```js
$('.qrg-products:empty').each((i, el) => {
  $(el).prev().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="title">Snack</h2>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <li>Chips</li>
  <li>Fruit</li>
  <li>Cookies</li>
</ul>

<h2 class="title">Candy</h2>
<ul class="qrg-products"></ul>

<h2 class="title">Drinks</h2>
<ul class="qrg-products">
  <li>Pop</li>
  <li>Water</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>

<h2 class="title">Desserts</h2>
<ul class="qrg-products"></ul>
```

Comment: .find("li") worked without changing html, although recommended. See my answer